# getting strange error code when trying to open MainActivity

Tags: java, android, program-entry-point

I am working on my Android project (I'm kind of beginner at Android and Android Studio)

I wanted to open my MainActivity class and here's what I've got:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <name="Gradle: androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0@aar">
    <ANNOTATIONS>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/00bc847ce5b9e3ce7b40d465bffbf9e9/drawerlayout-1.0.0/annotations.zip!/" />
    </ANNOTATIONS>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/00bc847ce5b9e3ce7b40d465bffbf9e9/drawerlayout-1.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/00bc847ce5b9e3ce7b40d465bffbf9e9/drawerlayout-1.0.0/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.drawerlayout/drawerlayout/1.0.0/9ecd4ecb7da215ba4c5c3e00bf8d290dad6f2bc5/drawerlayout-1.0.0-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

I have no idea what it means. My `MainActivity` did not look like this. It has a `GridView` and it is the main menu of my program. I am not sure what happened.

Comment: Just close all programs restart the system

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the menu of Android Studio select `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and then click the `Invalidate and Restart` button. After that when Android Studio started select `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project`.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project or running gradle build . If the issue still persists , then your Android Studio is kind of messed up and will show some warning . Please attach that warning too.

Comment: I've created a new project but it' no problem, no error in main

Answer (score 0):

Close Android studio and then delete the caches folder C:\Users\user_name.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of your asnwers solved my problem, I've tried them all...
Luckily I've saved an earlier version of this project in case something go wrong and just copied its `MainActivity.java`'s code and pasted into my current wrong `MainActivity.java` and now it seems working. Fortunately not many changes needed.